# Gazebo Classic - How to make a directional light source flash?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, plugin, gazebo-11, gazebo-plugins

I want to control the (flashing) behavior of a directional light source using a plugin. I came across the [FlashLightPlugin](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=flashlight_plugin) which controls the flashing behavior of a point source..

I thought I could bring the flashing behavior for a directional source by changing the light properties and so I made a copy of the [world file used in FlashLightPlugin tutorial](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/gazebo11/worlds/flash_light_plugin_demo.world) & replaced [these](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/fc2643c139a9f9627f235295c760a6afc348b0af/worlds/flash_light_plugin_demo.world#L27C1-L41) lines with the below code while keeping the remaining parts of the file untouched (If it's easier to follow, [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SSdg_rhezgLU5bMNl9jSLoBQkxZzZzR2/view?usp=drive_link) is the updated world file I used):

```
<light name='light_source1' type='directional'>
  <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
  <pose frame=''>0.25 0 0.25 0 -0.7854 0</pose>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.9</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
  <specular>1 0 0 1</specular>
  <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
</light>
```

I launched this updated world file with `gazebo updated_file.world`.
This spawned a directional source with the above properties but it is not flashing. It is staying static. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15mgoTG3ubCllM35UXCVlIQxH37VVpy0l/view?usp=drive_link) is the recording from Gazebo (Red light spread everywhere is the directional source of interest).

Can anyone help me understand how to make a directional light source flash?

Thanks!